# Is the question really on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm referring to this one:

[How to deal with bad coworkers and fellows?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/473/how-to-deal-with-bad-coworkers-and-fellows)

I'm sure it's a real problem and a very important issue for the OP, but does it really belong here? It seems more like something for workplace.SE as I don't see anything specifically Ismal related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe he is just looking for an answer from an islamic perspective. On how to treat him in a way it is permissible in islam etc or perhaps even some specific Dua's that would fit in these situations.

Comment: I think the question should be clarified to make it clear that the OP is looking for an Islamic viewpoint if that is the case.

Comment: I agree. I would find the question more acceptable with an appropriate edit.

Answer (score 0):

I would say so. The OP is looking for ways to deal with his peers and coworkers, while still following the rules of Islam.